# How to use thread in seekbar with android mediaplayer

Tags: android

how  to Create a thread that will check the song position every second and move the seekbar based on the song position?  i used it's below coding that's not work.in this code the seek bar worked as very first song

```
public void onFinish() {

        seconds.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // media Player
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        final ArrayList plsong = new ArrayList( b.getCharSequenceArrayList("song"));
        final ArrayList soname = new ArrayList(b.getCharSequenceArrayList("songname"));
        int i = 0;
        // media player load

        int index = 0;

        sname.setText((CharSequence) soname.get(i));
        Log.i("MP : ", plsong.get(i).toString());

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(player.this, (Integer) plsong.get(i));
        seekbar.setProgress(0);
        total = mp.getDuration();
        mp.start();
        seekbar.setMax(total);
        ct.start();
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new seekbarchange());

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {

                Thread ct1=new Thread();
                mp.release();
                sname.setText(" ");
                if (j < (plsong.size() - 1)) {
                    j++;
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(player.this,(Integer) plsong.get(j));
                    seekbar.setProgress(0);
                    total = mp.getDuration();
                    sname.setText((CharSequence) soname.get(j));
                    seekbar.setMax(total);
                    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new seekbarchange());
                    mp.start(); 
                    ct1.start();
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);




                }
            }
        });
        // seekbar progress


    }

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        seconds.setText((millisUntilFinished / 1000) + "");
        System.out.println("Timer  : " + (millisUntilFinished / 1000));

    }
    Thread ct  = new Thread(this);

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            while(mp != null){
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what = currentPosition;
                threadHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private Handler threadHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            seekbar.setProgress(msg.what);
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the runnable thread i once declared in a music player i made. worked fine. hope it helps.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int currentPosition = 0;
            while (!musicThreadFinished) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    currentPosition = getCurrentPosition();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }
                final int total = getDuration(); //gets the duration of music file

                final String totalTime = getAsTime(total);//converts it to 
                final String curTime = getAsTime(currentPosition);

                musicSeekBar.setMax(total);
                musicSeekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                musicSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(getBufferPercentage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (isPlaying()) {
                            if (!playPauseButton.isChecked()) {
                                playPauseButton.setChecked(true);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (playPauseButton.isChecked()) {
                                playPauseButton.setChecked(false);
                            }
                        }
                        musicDuration.setText(totalTime);
                        musicCurLoc.setText(curTime);
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the thread you need...
i am using progress bar here instead of seekbar..

```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (mp!=null) {
                final int   progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();


              try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }


              progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  p.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                }
              });

            if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
          }}
           }).start();
}

private int doSomeTasks(){
    if(mp!=null){
         int i=mp.getCurrentPosition();
    int t=mp.getDuration();
    if(t!=0){
    int d=(i*100)/t;

    return d;}
    else return 0;

    }
    return 0;

}
```